# html code appear in the page as source and not executed by browser

Tags: php, html, domdocument

my code is like that:

```
$link = "<a class=\"openevent\" href=\"$finalUrl\" target=\"_blank\">Open Event</a>";
foreach ($spans as $span) {
if ($span->getAttribute('class') == 'category') {
$span->nodeValue .= $link;
    }
}
```

the problem here is that the `$link` variable is echo in the page as html source as this

```
<a class="openevent" href="http://www.mysite.com/Free-Live-Streaming-Video-Online-Other-Cycling-Cycling-The-Tour-of-Britain-170638.html" target="_blank">Open Event</a>
```

instead of appearing as usual hyperlink

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: is it a DOMDocument ? have you tried to create the `a` node manually ?

Comment: yes it domdocument how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding text to the spans' node value, to add an anchor node you'll have to create an anchor node with [`createElement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) and add the [attributes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) to it then [append](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) it to the span.

---

```
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    if ($span->getAttribute('class') == 'category') {    
        $link = $doc->createElement('a', 'Open Event');
        $link->setAttribute("class", "openevent");
        $link->setAttribute("href", $finalUrl);
        $link->setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        $span->appendChild($link);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, using nodeValue will cause the HTML characters to be escaped (much like htmlspecialchars() ), and thus you see them on screen.

Comment: @Musa Can please help me with this and show the code according to your suggestion

Comment: @mirandakerry if you follow the links in the answer you'll see how to do each step.

Comment: @Musa here is my try but not working `    $link = "<a class=\"openevent\" href=\"$finalUrl\" target=\"_blank\">Open Event</a>";
    $node = $doc->createElement("link");
    $newnode = $doc->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute('class', 'openevent');`

Comment: @Musa thank u very much you just saved me alot of research time

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are building some kind of xml in foreach. when you build xml it encodes the html characters '<' as ∓gt; so while print you will not actually print the html. may be html_entity_decode function will work for you.

```
echo html_entity_decode($doc->saveHTML())
```